# Error creating table named 0e7cc62d5339491aa701b67453405ccb in MySQL

Tags: python, mysql

So I'm running a Python script that's making some tables in my MySQL database, and I keep getting the following error:

```
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 174, in execute
self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
File "build/bdist.linux-i686/egg/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
raise errorclass, errorvalue

ProgrammingError: (1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds
to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 
'0e7cc62d5339491aa701b67453405ccb (\n\t   email  VARCHAR(50),\n\t   price' at line 1")
```

The thing is, it only gives the error when I try to create the table named `0e7cc62d5339491aa701b67453405ccb`, other than that, the script runs fine!

Here's the code from the area that the error occurs:

```
def add(i, p, e):
conn = MySQLdb.connect(...)  
cursor = conn.cursor()
e = str(e)
d = str(hashlib.md5(e).hexdigest())
i = str(i)
p = str(p)
q = """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS %s (
         email  VARCHAR(50),
         price  VARCHAR(15),
         isbn VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (isbn))""" % (d,)
print e
print "<br />"
print i
print "<br />"
print p
print "<br />"
print "<p />"

cursor.execute(q)


q = """REPLACE INTO %s (email,price,isbn)
     VALUES (%%s,%%s,%%s)""" % (d,)

cursor.execute(q, (e,p,i,))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem lies in the table name `0e7cc62d5339491aa701b67453405ccb` starting with `0e7`. Escape the table name with backticks (`` ` ``) and it should work. However, as @Randy says this naming scheme is a bad idea. Unless you have very good reason, I'd seriously consider improving it.

Quoting [the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/identifiers.html):

> It is recommended that you do not use
>   names that begin with Me or MeN, where
>   M and N are integers. For example,
>   avoid using 1e as an identifier,
>   because an expression such as 1e+3 is
>   ambiguous. Depending on context, it
>   might be interpreted as the expression
>   1e + 3 or as the number 1e+3.

Comment: Out of interest, I wonder why it says "Me *or* MeN". If it begins with MeN, then it begins with Me!

Comment: I'm trying to give each email address its own table, and I thought that tables couldn't handle non alphanumeric characters. Any other suggestions?

Comment: @Parker You should start a new question for that, giving full details: your current schema, why you are creating a table per user, etc. I don't know enough to give you a real answer without that.